# How to compare two Lists and if the values are not the same add to another list

Tags: list, compare

I have 3 lists

```
final List<Locais> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Locais> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Locais> finallist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add the values from list1 to the finallist

```
 for (Locais locais : list1) {
            String name = locais.getName();
            finallist.add(locais);
                        }
```

Now I wanted to compare list2 with the finallist. If a value from list2 does not exist in the finallist, add it to the finallist. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a clean way, create a list called differences. Initialize it with all `list2` elements, then remove all elements that the `finallist` has, you can do it using `removeAll` method from List API. This makes it contain the differences between `list2` and `finallist`, then iterate over the differences and push them into the `finallist`.

```
List<String> differences = new ArrayList<>(list2);
differences.removeAll(finallist);
for(Locais locais : differences){
   finallist.add(locais)
}
```

For further information about removeAll check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the "removeAll" is not to eliminate the repeated values, any idea what might be happening?

Comment: That may be because you are using objects without overloading the equals method. In the java internals, to decide whether 2 objects are similar, it uses the .equals() method. However, the equals method uses references to decide. If you need to check equality using another property of the class, then you need to overload the equals method, or just use another trick to get it done.

Answer (score -1):

run an enhanced for loop for every element in list2. Have an if in the for loop. if !finallist.contains(locais) then finallist.add(locais)

hope this helps bud